# friendly-id, checking two models/tables for existing slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Imagine the following route:

```
get ':slug/:location'
```

where :search is triggering a finder on two different models (ie. Businnes, Person) based on the slug provided.

The problem I'm currently facing is that I couldn't find a way to check two different models for existing slugs while generating a new one.

**tl;dr**:
I'm trying to avoid the situation where two different models are given the same slug.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is run a custom validator in each of your models, this one would go in your Business model, for example:

```
before_save :unique_slug

private

def unique_slug
  self.slug = self.name + "-" + self.id unless
    self.find_by_slug(:slug).blank? and Person.find_by_slug(:slug).blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: yep, but that's not how friendly-id behaves when it finds an already existing slug (and not exactly i had in mind). I want friendly-id to just generate a new one (ie. by appending uuid).

Comment: In that case, you can just have it set the ID to something else if the error occurs, I'll update my answer to have it do that.